# most efficient way to convert text file contents into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

The following code essentially does the following:

1. Takes file contents and reads it into two lists (stripping and splitting)
2. Zips the two lists together into a dictionary
3. Uses the dictionary to create a "login" feature.

My question is: is there an easier more efficient (quicker) method of creating the dictionary from the file contents:

**File:**

```
user1,pass1
user2,pass2
```

**Code**

```
def login():
    print("====Login====")

    usernames = []
    passwords = []
    with open("userinfo.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.strip().split(",")
            usernames.append(fields[0])  # read all the usernames into list usernames
            passwords.append(fields[1])  # read all the passwords into passwords list

            # Use a zip command to zip together the usernames and passwords to create a dict
    userinfo = zip(usernames, passwords)  # this is a variable that contains the dictionary in the 2-tuple list form
    userinfo_dict = dict(userinfo)
    print(userinfo_dict)

    username = input("Enter username:")
    password = input("Enter password:")

    if username in userinfo_dict.keys() and userinfo_dict[username] == password:
        loggedin()
    else:
        print("Access Denied")
        main()
```

For your answers, please:

a) Use the existing function and code to adapt
b) provide explanations /comments (especially for the use of split/strip)
c) If with json/pickle, include all the necessary information for a beginner to access

Thanks in advance

Comment: never keep passwords in cleartext, you should use some kind of hashing function e.g. https://passlib.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just by using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents) :

```
import csv

with  open("userinfo.txt") as file:
    list_id = csv.reader(file)
    userinfo_dict = {key:passw  for key, passw in list_id}

print(userinfo_dict)
>>>{'user1': 'pass1', 'user2': 'pass2'}
```

`with open()` is the same type of context manager you use to open the file, and handle the close.

`csv.reader` is the method that loads the file, it returns an object you can iterate directly, like in a comprehension list.  But instead of using a comprehension list, this use a comprehension dict.

To build a dictionary with a comprehension style, you can use this syntax :

```
new_dict = {key:value for key, value in list_values} 
# where list_values is a sequence of couple of values, like tuples: 
# [(a,b), (a1, b1), (a2,b2)]
```

Comment: can you please explain, for beginners and teaching purposes, the key:passw for key part. could any variables be used there, I assume? Also could you comment to say what precisely it is doing (no that line I mean)

Comment: MissComputing thanks for your feedback, keep in mind @endo.anaconda 's comment, next step is to replace the passwords by the some hash

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `csv` module you can simply do something like:

```
userinfo_dict = dict() # prepare dictionary
with open("userinfo.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f: # for each line in your file
        (key, val) = line.strip().split(',')
        userinfo_dict[key] = val
# now userinfo_dict is ready to be used
```